# One element only subarray max length

Tags: algorithm, ruby

**Task description**

> You are given a list and an item, find the length of the longest consecutive subsequence of the list containing only the item.

**Testcases**

```
[1, 1, 2, 3] 1 -> 2
[1, 0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 6] 0 -> 3
```

This code is pretty readable in my opinion but I fear that the \$O(N^2)\$ time complexity is sub-optimal.

```
def subsequences(arr)
  ((0...arr.length).to_a)
    .repeated_permutation(2)
    .select {|start, finish| finish >= start}
    .collect {|start, finish| arr[start..finish] }
end 

def longest_item_only_subsequence_len(arr, item)
   subsequences(arr)
     .select {|seq| seq.all? {|i| i == item} }
     .max_by(&:length)
     .length
end

p subsequences([1, 2, 3])
p longest_item_only_subsequence_len([1, 0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 6], 0)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `chunk` is the way to go. I'd write it differently, though, using a list-comphehension approach (in Ruby: `map`+`if`+`compact`. Or with a [custom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310426/list-comprehension-in-ruby) method.) and taking in account the edge case (no elements `item` in the array):

```
def longest_item_only_subsequence_len(xs, item)
  xs.chunk(&:itself).map { |y, ys| ys.size if y == item }.compact.max || 0
end
```

Comment: `ys.size if y == item` equals `y == item ? ys.size : nil` right?

Comment: Right. In fact, I like it with `?` better because it looks more like an expression, but the other looks more like a list-comprehension. Take your pick.

Comment: As a minor comment, which spacing style is reccomended in Ruby? All on one line or each method call on its own line?

Comment: IMO: if it fits in one line, one line. If I think it's too long, I give it a name and use it in another line.

Comment: To me separate lines help for chronological order, top before, then bottom. It is subjective though.

Comment: It's also ok, just a matter of taste. Left-to-right looks also chronological, tough :)

Comment: I accepted as this solution requires no special handling of the case where the item is not present

Answer (score 1):

After some more thinking, I realized that `Array.chunk` is `O(N)` and what I was looking for:

```
 def longest_item_only_subsequence_len(arr, item)
   return 0 if ! arr.include?(item)
   arr
    .chunk(&:itself)
    .select{|kind, _| kind == item}
    .collect {|_, subseq| subseq}
    .max_by(&:length)
    .length
end
```

Comment: This last `length` probably fails when `arr` has no `item` in it.

Comment: @tokland I may just add a check at the start of the function, but maybe it should fail. Not finding a subsequence is exceptional. (An empty subsequence counts in your opinion?)

Comment: Yes, I think the code should just work (return 0) if there is no `item` item in the sequence.